# Queue based on LinkedList , cannot return null pointer when creating new Queue

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I am trying to create a Queue base on LinkedList in C.
and I have an issue that when I tried to initialize the Queue and return QueueNode = NULL;
it still gives me a memory address and when a tried to check if the Queue is empty the result is always not.
if I let the Queue pointer = NULL in the main is work (the pointer is equal to null).
attach mine code.

QueueNode Header:

```
typedef struct node
{
    queueInfo value;
    struct node* next;
}QueueNode;


QueueNode* createQueue();
int isEmptyQueue(QueueNode* Q);
void insert(QueueNode** Q, queueInfo x);
void delafter(QueueNode* p, queueInfo* x);
void PrintQueue(QueueNode* Q);
```

QueueNode.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



QueueNode* createQueue()
{
    /*
    Aim:     Initiolaze new Queue;
    input:   nothing
    outpot:  returns QueueNode pointer 
    */
    QueueNode* Q = NULL;
    Q->next = NULL;
    return Q;
}

int isEmptyQueue(QueueNode* Q)
{
    /*
    Aim:     check if the Queue is empty
    input:   pointer to an queue
    outpot:  returns 1 if the queue is empty, 0 if not
    */
    if ((!Q))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

main:

```
{
    QueueNode* q = createQueue;
    int res = isEmptyQueue(q);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

pictures from debug mode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpZWU.png)

Comment: OT: `Q->next = NULL;` Dereferencing a NULL pointer results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: In `createQueue`, try: `QueueNode* Q = malloc(sizeof(*Q));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Improper attempt to assign `.next`**

> I am trying to create a Queue base on LinkedList in C. and I have an issue that when I tried to initialize the Queue and return `QueueNode = NULL;`

Assigning `NULL` to `Q` is OK, yet `Q->next = NULL;` is undefined behavior (UB) as `Q` does not point too valid memory.  Simply do not attempt `Q->next = NULL` since it is not needed.

```
QueueNode* Q = NULL;
// Q->next = NULL;
return Q;
```

**Warnings not all enabled**

`QueueNode* q = createQueue;` attempts to assign the address of a function to a `QueueNode` pointer.  Instead, call the function.  A well warning enabled  compiler would warn about this.

```
// QueueNode* q = createQueue;
QueueNode* q = createQueue();
```